# DateTime is missing GetObjectData. Or am I missing something?

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, interface

As far as I remember Concrete implements Interfaces :)
Looking at DateTime struct seems to implement ISerializable. Which suppose to implement:

```
void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
```

I can't really find this implementation on the meta data of DateTime.
Also:

```
DateTime.Now.GetObjectData(null,null);
```

Seems to throw compile time exception. I haven't checked ILSpy yet...

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISerializable is [explicity implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). You can call the method like this:

```
ISerializable now = DateTime.Now;
now.GetObjectData(null, new StreamingContext());
//don't send null for the first parameter
```

Comment: @AmirKatz From the MSDN link: When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface.

Comment: Awesome.. I wasn't aware that Explicit is not visible. You learn new stuff every day :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the source for [DateTime](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/OperationInvokerBehavior.cs#3ed6aaa40339f61a). It uses explicit interface implementation when implementing `ISerializable`, meaning it isn't visible via calls to a `DateTime` instance.

```
void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        ....
}
```

Notice the method name is prefixed with `ISerializable`. You'd need to treat the `DateTime` instance as an `ISerializable` instance to access the method.